# Why does my PHP page respond with the whole HTML source, and not just the data I’m echoing?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to communicate back and forth with the server with the help of jQuery.

This is my simple scenario:

1. Send data through html form using jQuery post method.
2. Receive data on the server side end echo it back again.
3. Receive same data on the client side in the form of jQuery callback and do something with data (console.log in the broser)

**Now my problem is that php is returning source html code with tags, instead of data that has been received ? 
So if I type "Hello" in the form field on the client side, php is returning whole html source from the page. Why is that ?**

Html:

```
<form action="#">
     <textarea name="content" id="content" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p><button>Click to submit</button></p>
    </form>
```

jquery:

```
    (function(){
            $("form").on("submit",function(e){
                $.post("save.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
                    alert(data);
                })
            e.preventDefault();
            })
    }());
```

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $_POST['content'];
        ?> 
    <script src=""></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code is very necessary

Comment: The code is pretty necessary, unless someone has had the exact same issue as you.

Comment: It's a poor question without code to evaluate.

Comment: Php tags might not be closed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery post() calls the correct url? Check with your debugging tools in your browser, under the Network tab to see if the connection url is correct.

Comment: yes, url is absolutely correct. it is posting to save.php, but the response is problem. I am receiving value entered in the form togather with html source code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a complete html page back to the browser, that's why you don't receive only the data. Change your php file to the following and it should work as expected:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['content'];
?>
```

## Why did PHP return a whole html page in your case?

1. PHP parses the whole save.php file
2. If there are no `<?php ?>` tags, the whole content is left untouched and will be sent to the browser as it is
3. If it finds any `<?php ?>` tags the parser interprets the code and outputs it in the same place

### Example

save.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $_POST['content'];
        ?> 
    <script src=""></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The parser finds one `<?php ?>` tag:

```
        <?php
            echo $_POST['content'];
        ?>
```

And interprets it: (simply assuming that `$_POST['content'] == 'john smith'`)

```
        john smith
```

Now, the interpreted code gets inserted and replaces the php tag in the original content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        john smith
    <script src=""></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, this is sent to the browser and gets processed by the jQuery Ajax callback.

Comment: it is working, but why php returned whole html in the first case ?
it is supposed to echo only content of the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is your save.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $_POST['content'];
        ?> 
    <script src=""></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just do a json_encode and parse jSON with your ajax call :

**save.php**

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST['content']);
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post("save.php",
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    }, 'json');
```